# Get a list of Azure OS Disks attached to VMs in specific subscription

Tags: python, azure, disk, azure-cli

I am fetching a list of OS Disks attached to VMs in Azure in all resource groups of specific subscription. I found a [AZ utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/disk?view=azure-cli-latest#az_disk_list) to fetch the list in json format.

Using below sequence I am able to get the list in json format, Is there any similar way to get this achieved using any python module ?

```
az login
az account set --subscription <subscription>
az disk list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could use method [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/python/api/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2017_05_10.operations.resourcesoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_resource_resources_v2017_05_10_operations_ResourcesOperations_list) to get disks in your subscription.

For example:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient, SubscriptionClient

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = ''

# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = ''

# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = ''

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    secret = KEY,
    tenant = TENANT_ID
)

subscription_id = ''

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

disks = compute_client.disks.list()
for disk in disks:
    print disk
```

Note: It will return all disks in your subscription. But it is possible some disks are not OS disk, they maybe Data disk or a disk that not attach for a VM.

Comment: But the python script result is equal to `az disk list`

Comment: You also could check python managed disk sdk in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.disksoperations?view=azure-python

Comment: Thanks Shengbao ! That helped me a lot.

Comment: Note: link changed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.disksoperations